# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xcode6, cpanel

i uploaded my php config code to my server befirstw on cpanel ...under the public html ..
my php file is

```html
<?php

$dbhost = "befirstwin.com";
$dbname = "befirstw_intlgent";
$dbuser = "befirstw_intelli";
$dbpass = "Ngcp1988$ ";


$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
die("database connection failed: " .
mysql_connect_error() . "("  . mysql_connect_errno() .")"
);
}
$username = isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : '';
$password = isset($_GET['password']) ? $_GET['password'] : '';

$query = "INSERT INTO users 
           VALUES ('', '$username', '$password')";

$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

if(!$result)
{
die("we have problem");
}

mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

i am getting this error
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'befirstw_intelli'@'s147.adk-media.com' (using password: YES) in /home/befirstw/public_html/connectimagedb.php on line 8

if you have any idea or any thing more required for php connectivity plz suggest

Comment: The error message is not clear to you because?

Comment: use this as $dbhost='s147.adk-media.com'

Comment: The error is pretty much telling you everything. What else do you need to know?

Answer (score 1):

I check that $ sign in the password is creating problem in my case.Please Do not use $ or any other special Character that may create problem. In my case $ sign in password was creating problem

Comment: Again i faced this problem but now with other special character, if you face this problem then change password and then check once again

Answer (score 1):

This could simply be caused by an incorrect password. In your `$dbpass`, is the space at the end supposed to be there? That extra space before the close `"` would add a space to the end of the password, causing it to be a different password.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if you are opening a connection. I notice the line, where it is closing a connection but not sure if you have opened a connection? Where is is your execute statement for the Insert Query?

Thanks

Comment: its just working fine with local host but when i try to connect via hosting dress with my actual credentials its not working

Comment: is their any thing else required with this file in order to execute in hosting server or this file is enough

Comment: @moeen or the other thign is the host name. That could be wrong. Have you got the correct $dbhostname?

Comment: if host name is wrong then,directly message popup browser file did`t found ..

Comment: IF I PUT WRONG HOST ADRESS BROWSER THROW THAT ERROR..

Comment: Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host 'befirstwin.comiuAHJDHJSJSAJDJXN' (2) in /home/befirstw/public_html/connectimagedb.php on line

Comment: Remove the space $dbpass = "Ngcp1988$ " in between the quotes, after the '$' in your password and try it @moeen

Comment: I have a feeling that could be it @moeen

Comment: Tell me if it works @moeen

Comment: yup still same error bro !!!

Comment: I am not sure. If I find a solution, I shall post it. SOrrryy @moeen

Comment: Did you check the username and the password is correct @moeen? I know its a stupid question.

Comment: I went to your website http://befirstwin.com/ but its full of errors. @moeen Can you show me the page where you are getting the Acccess denied error? Thankss.